# Invalid Request Error When Creating A New DriveItem

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

We're getting the following error when we try to create a new driveItem. I checked the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) but everything seems fine. I'm not experienced with this API but can it be that something changed recently? It says the 'parentReference' was not allowed there but it clearly is, looking at the [documentation of driveItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). We didn't change the code too. Any ideas?

Request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/children
SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.5.0
{
    "file": {},
    "name": "....pdf",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!CI0Uhi...",
        "id": "01BRIXMT..."
    }
}
```

Response:

```
400 : Bad Request
Transfer-Encoding : chunked
Strict-Transport-Security : max-age=31536000
Cache-Control : no-store, no-cache
x-ms-ags-diagnostic : {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"005","RoleInstance":"SN4PEPF0000085A"}}
client-request-id : 535b6eab-c9ad-45a2-9bc9-7264c935014d
Vary : Accept-Encoding
request-id : 202ce588-4f71-436c-b9f2-28e95a572eda
Date : Fri, 11 Nov 2022 20:18:32 GMT
Content-Type : application/json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "The item cannot contain a parentReference",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2022-11-11T20:18:33",
      "request-id": "202ce588-4f71-436c-b9f2-28e95a572eda",
      "client-request-id": "535b6eab-c9ad-45a2-9bc9-7264c935014d"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not allowed when creating a new DriveItem, as all required information is already present in the request's path (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/children). Did you try simply without parentReference?

Comment: Do you want to create a folder or a file?

Comment: I want to create a file. Actually, I don't want to change how we're calling this API because nothing has changed in our code but this endpoint started failing. I'm suspecting something has changed on the API.

Comment: Are you saying this type of call has worked in the past?? When using this API endpoint  "parentReference" is not supported in the  body of the request - as indicated by Christoph Dahlen above.

Comment: How we're calling the API is not changed. I'll check the dependencies to make sure. But the documentation suggests that parentReference is allowed in the request, as it's listed as a property.

Comment: I've opened this ticket but the response was something that is expected: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1087833/invalid-request-error-when-creating-a-new-driveite.html